# cpp files are not generated for capnp_generate_cpp()

Tags: cmake, capnproto

I have temp.capnp file where my cmake file has

```
find_package(CapnProto CONFIG REQUIRED)
include_directories(${CAPNP_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_definitions(${CAPNP_DEFINITIONS})

set(CAPNPC_SRC_PREFIX "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}" CACHE STRING "" FORCE)
set(CAPNPC_OUTPUT_DIR "." CACHE STRING "" FORCE)
file(MAKE_DIRECTORY "${CAPNPC_OUTPUT_DIR}")

capnp_generate_cpp(CAPNP_SOURCES CAPNP_HEADERS temp.capnp)
```

with this, it does not generate respective files for capnp, it does not give any error as well. what I am missing here?

Comment: Add some `MESSAGE()` statements to `CapnProtoMacros.cmake` to print out values in order to see where it is going wrong.

Comment: @metal do I have to write anymore `.cmake` files? where can i find `CapnProtoMacros.cmake`? I just have one `cmake.Lists` file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Macro `capnp_generate_cpp` generates files in form of the `add_custom_command`, that is, nothing is performed unless some target **depends** on these files.

The most simple form of such dependency is produced by `add_executable`:

```
# Create rules for generate source and header files.
capnp_generate_cpp(CAPNP_SOURCES CAPNP_HEADERS temp.capnp)
# Consume these files for executable.
add_executable(foo main.cpp ${CAPNP_SOURCES} ${CAPNP_HEADERS})
```

BTW, such example is provided in the description for [CapnProtoConfig.cmake](https://github.com/capnproto/capnproto/blob/master/c%2B%2B/cmake/CapnProtoConfig.cmake.in) script, which is processed via `find_package(CapnProto)`. (Do not forget about other lines in this example for make the executable built successfully).